# How can I install all deps in NODE_ENV production?

Tags: node.js, npm

As part of my CI pipeline I want to install all of the dependencies (`devDependencies` and `dependencies`).
Also I want to run the tests in the `production` environment (`NODE_ENV`= production).
But when I set the production env and `npm install`, it skip the devdeps.

How can I combine `NODE_ENV=production` with devdeps installation?

Comment: when you put `NODE_ENV=production` it will ignore devDependencies, you might ignore putting this NODE_ENV to production.

Comment: What are you using for the CI pipeline? Can't you separate the build and test phases? Build as development then run tests as production

Answer (score 2):

It is written [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description) that npm will not install `devDependencies` when `NODE_ENV=production`.
To go around, you can try to force the installation of `devDependencies` by running `npm install --only=dev`.

Comment: Because he's using a continuous integration server. Basically he has hired/programmed a robot to be a new developer in his team and that robot needs to build the code so needs dev dependencies but then he wants to ask the robot to test production environment.. and the robot is confused

Answer (score 1):

`devDependencies` suppose to be install during development, not production, so u need to `npm install` without set `NODE_ENV=production`, but u have to run `NODE_ENV=production npm start`